# Deployment of SQL Server Express database fails

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-express

I have to deploy ASP.Net application with remote database connection in IIS server.

Deployment has worked fine without database. And I was able to run that application on the IIS server.

Coming to the application with remote database I have given the connection string in C# code. And it is connected.

My `web.config` has thsi connection string :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have replaced that with my database connection credentials as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=RemoteHost,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;user Id=MyUserId;Password=MyPassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In Package/Publish options I have selected (Import from web.config) and deployed that. Then I got the following error:

> *Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data
>   "Data Source=RemoteHost,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;user
>   Id=MyUserId;Password=MyPassword" cannot be created.)*
>
> *Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path  "Data Source=RemoteHost,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;user
>   Id=MyUserId;Password=MyPassword" cannot be created.*
>
> *The source is invalid.
>
>   Script failed for Database 'DBNAME'.
>
>   Script failed for Database 'DBNAME'.
>
>   Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

I am new to ASP.Net. Anybody please help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you see your connection string in IIS is the same in VS?

Comment: I want to deploy to the IIs in my own PC. The DB is the same for both the servers. And In Package/Publish options of SQL i don't have specified any destination connection string. First i tried to Build the deployment package and it is failed.

Comment: ok I post the Walkthrough link for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't configure Web deployment package correct you can do that right Click on Project ,Select Properties  and go to package/Publish SQL 
I have add link for Walkthrough: Deploying a Web Application Project Using a Web Deployment Package (Part 1 of 4) for VS2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have SQL in my system. I am connecting to a remote sql server. Is it possible to create a DataBase in that system from my system as destination database..? R is it possible to use the same database for both source and destination..?

Comment: yes. you can but really becaous i don't use remote sql server. I don't know how. just read the Walkthrough it will give you Answer